# Composer solo funciona en la particion C: del rigido, pero no en la D:

Tags: cmd, composer

He instalado Composer en Windows con el instalador que he descargado de la página de Composer. Una vez instalado abro el CMD y estando ubicado en C: ejecuto el comando "composer" y me devuelve que versión de Composer se ha instalado como así tambien el listado de comandos disponibles que tiene Composer.
O sea Composer se ha instalado correctamente y puedo ejecuatrlo desde la partición C:

Pero si desde el CMD, me ubico en la partición D: y ejecuto el comado "composer" no me muestra nada. No es que me da un error de comando desconocido, no me muestra nada

Necesito usar Composer en D. Es allí en donde tengo mis proyectos

Comment: Te responde sin importar en qué carpeta estás ubicado en el C, pero no responde, sin importar en qué carpeta estés ubicado en el D?

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que me sucede